# How to remove frames from a video file recorded with Aforge

Tags: c#, wpf, video, buffer, aforge

I have to implement via software a CCTV circuit with AForge.
I can write a video file with

```
 private VideoFileWriter FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
```

and write a new frame with

```
private void LocalWebCam_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   try
   {
      Image img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
       ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       bi = new BitmapImage();
       bi.BeginInit();
       bi.StreamSource = ms;
       bi.EndInit();

       bi.Freeze();
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
       { frameHolder.Source = bi; }));

       FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(BitmapImage2Bitmap(bi));
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {}
}
```

So the file writing by frame adding is fine.

So in order not to fill the hd with huge files I decide for example that when the avi file reaches 10MBs it is split to a new file

1.avi is renamed to 2.avi and a new file is started

> 1.avi --> 2.avi

then

> 1.avi --> 2.avi --> 3.avi

and so on. Eventually when I will have 1.avi 2.avi... 10.avi 11.avi I will delete 11.avi
so to always have 10 file. A rolling system.
And that works but is not smart all.

What would be great instead is that of file dividing when reaching a certain size I continue adding the new frames at the end AND I remove the new frames at the beginning so that the whole avi file size does not exceeds a certain size and I ALWAYS have the last minutes of registration

[image]

Comment: No idea how to do what you ask. But something very simple could be, instead of all this naming and renaming just to name your files like yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.avi and next to that have a FileSystemWatcher to deleting old files as soon as there more than 10 files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-6.0

Comment: Yes sure I could do that ... but the other solution (if feasible) would be better wouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: Yeah sure... never worked with that control. The docs say something about a TimeSpan FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(BitmapImage2Bitmap(bi), TimeSpan);, maybe you can write a new file with from a certain time span of the old file and at the end of the new file. But that still means writing to a new file and deleting the old one. http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/84a560df-bfd5-e0d6-2812-f810b56a254d.htm

Comment: It's not clear what codec, but in any case - first frame in the file will be keyframe, containing all information (basically full image). However, subsequent frames will likely be non-keyframes and will depend on that first  frame. So you can't just delete first frame.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if such a functionality exists. But you can try a different approach of storing the Bitmap frames as a buffer, and making a `VideoFileWriter` whenever you need it.

You could make a class to store the frames as an array of `Bitmap`, and then make it as a video whenever you want to. Here is a simple class to do the same.

```cs
    public class CustomVideoBuffer
    {
        public readonly int BufferSize;
        protected readonly Bitmap[] Buffer;
        protected int currentFrame;
        public CustomVideoBuffer(int bufferSize = 100)
        {
            BufferSize = bufferSize;
            Buffer = new Bitmap[BufferSize];
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
        public void AddFrame(Bitmap image)
        {
            Buffer[currentFrame++] = image;
            currentFrame %= BufferSize;
        }
        public VideoFileWriter GetVideo()
        {
            var FileWriter = new VideoFileWriter(); // Create an instance here
            int frame = currentFrame;
            do
            {
                var img = Buffer[++frame];
                if (img!=null) 
                    FileWriter.WriteVideoFrame(img);
                frame %= BufferSize;
            } while (frame != currentFrame); // start from (currentFrame+1), and cycle all frames till currentFrame
            return FileWriter;
        }
    }
```

Next, create an instance of this class in your program as

```cs
CustomVideoBuffer myBuffer = new CustomVideoBuffer(300); // Create a buffer of size 300
```

Then, add frames one by one as shown

```cs
private void LocalWebCam_NewFrame(object sender, AForge.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   try
   {
       // Get Bitmap converted from the eventArgs
       Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

       myBuffer.AddFrame(img); // Add the frame to the buffer
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { ... }
}
```

Finally, when you are done, just obtain the prepared VideoFileWriter() from your buffer with

```cs
VideoFileWriter FileWriter = myBuffer.GetVideo();
```

Comment: While not exactly what i was hoping for, this apporach seems to be the most reasonable considering you cannot "easily remove" frames from .AVIs . I think i will use this approach, thank you!

Comment: @DenisSchaf can you answer the comment about what codec you're putting into your AVI? Are you writing each frame inside the AVI as a `.bmp` format?

Comment: @DenisSchaf PS: I don't use AForge so not obvious if AForge always uses `VideoCodec.MPEG4` as the only option. If your AVI has RGB data or BMP formatted data then **you can** _"easily remove frames from .AVIs"_. The codec inside the AVI container will decide if it's hard (_eg:_ MPEG/H264 format) or else very easy (_eg:_ RGB/BMP format).

Comment: @VC.One is use 'videoWriter.Open(saveVideoPath, (int)liveImage.Width, (int)liveImage.Height, 30, VideoCodec.MPEG4, recordingBitrate);' so i use MPEG4 but i am flexible int that regard